# Cannot Find 'expo/bin/cli.js' Module - Issues with Expo CLI Installation and Updates

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-publish

hello I have this problem that I could not solve. I tried all methods, but they did not work  The error appears when i type on the  command  expo publish
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1di8a.png)

I have this problem that I could not solve. I tried all methods, but they did not work  The error appears when i type on the  command  expo publish